Oauth manual configuration .net
i need to config the oauth in my app manually, anyone have a tuto or documentation i can follow ?
authorization code flow
the client program.cs
`builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OAuth";
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOAuth("OAuth", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientId");
    options.ClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientSecret");
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CallbackPath"));

    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AuthorizationEndpoint");
    options.TokenEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TokenEndpoint");
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("access_token", accessToken)
            };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            context.Principal.AddIdentity(identity);
        }
    };
});`

the auth program.cs
`builder.Services.AddAuthentication("OAuth").AddJwtBearer("OAuth", options =>
{
    var secretBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Secret"));
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretBytes);

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        ValidIssuer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Issuer"),
        ValidAudience = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Audience"),
        IssuerSigningKey = key,
    };
});`

here the onpost for the login form

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            var redirectUri = Request.Form["redirect_uri"];

            if (IsValidUser(Email, Password))
            {
                // Generate authorization code
                var authorizationCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                //AuthCodes[authorizationCode] = Email; // Store the code along with user identifier

                // Construct redirect URI with authorization code and state
                var query = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "code", authorizationCode },
            //{ "state", state }
        };
                var redirectUrl = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(redirectUri, query);

                // Redirect back to client application with authorization code
                return Redirect(redirectUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // Invalid credentials, handle accordingly (e.g., display error message)
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { error = "Invalid credentials" });
            }

        }


the problem i m facing that after the user succesuflly logs in , the auth server dsnt redirect to the client app , it redirects to the auth /account/callback
CallbackPath=/account/callback
